# Write Multiple Documents to Firestore using python from 3rd party API

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to collect data from a 3rd party API, parse it and store the data points for each game in firestore collection.

So far I have got the code below which works but only writes the data for the last game instead of all the games available in the feed.

I have checked the API call and parsing code and it returns the correct data. So I assume it has something to do with the write to firebase section of the code.

The data needs to be updated for existing documents, or a new one created if the game data is not already in the collection. The API will be called a few times a day to ensure data is up to date.

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

```
import requests
from google.cloud import firestore
import json

client = firestore.Client(project='PROJECTNAME')


def bluebet_nba_odds(bluebet_nba_oods):
    # MAKE VARIABLES GLOBAL
    global away_team_win_odds, away_team, home_team_win_odds, home_team, start_time, event_title, event_id, competition

    # API CALL

    link = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com.au/json/reply/MasterCategoryRequest?EventTypeID=107&WithLevelledMarkets' \
           '=true&WithLevelledMarkets=true '
    # Request data from link as 'str'
    nbadata = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    nbadata = json.loads(nbadata)

    # JSON PARSE

    for nba_odds in nbadata['MasterCategories'][2]['Categories'][0]['MasterEvents']:
        competition = nba_odds['CategoryName']
        event_id = nba_odds['MasterEventId']
        event_title = nba_odds['MasterEventName']
        start_time = nba_odds['MaxAdvertisedStartTime']
        home_team = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['OutcomeName']
        home_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['Price']
        away_team = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['OutcomeName']
        away_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['Price']

    # WRITE TO FIRESTORE

    doc = client.collection('bluebet_nba_season_odds').document()
    doc.set({
        'competition': competition,
        'event_id': event_id,
        'event_title': event_title,
        'start_time': start_time,
        'home_team': home_team,
        'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
        'away_team': away_team,
        'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
    })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bluebet_nba_odds(bluebet_nba_odds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using for loop, ensure that all the needed actions are properly indented and make sure it's inside of it. The `doc.set()` is inline with the for loop which makes the for loop finish first and only the last game is being written or updated. See the fixed code below:

```
import requests
from google.cloud import firestore
import json

client = firestore.Client(project='PROJECTNAME')


def bluebet_nba_odds(bluebet_nba_oods):
    # MAKE VARIABLES GLOBAL
    global away_team_win_odds, away_team, home_team_win_odds, home_team, start_time, event_title, event_id, competition

    # API CALL

    link = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com.au/json/reply/MasterCategoryRequest?EventTypeID=107&WithLevelledMarkets' \
           '=true&WithLevelledMarkets=true '
    # Request data from link as 'str'
    nbadata = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    nbadata = json.loads(nbadata)

    # JSON PARSE

    for nba_odds in nbadata['MasterCategories'][2]['Categories'][0]['MasterEvents']:
        competition = nba_odds['CategoryName']
        event_id = nba_odds['MasterEventId']
        event_title = nba_odds['MasterEventName']
        start_time = nba_odds['MaxAdvertisedStartTime']
        home_team = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['OutcomeName']
        home_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['Price']
        away_team = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['OutcomeName']
        away_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['Price']

        # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
        # This would write to Firestore on every iteration instead of completing the loop first and then writing.

        doc = client.collection('bluebet_nba_season_odds').document()
        doc.set({
            'competition': competition,
            'event_id': event_id,
            'event_title': event_title,
            'start_time': start_time,
            'home_team': home_team,
            'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
            'away_team': away_team,
            'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
        })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bluebet_nba_odds(bluebet_nba_odds)
```

Comment: thanks. i got it working with some different formatting. The issue i have now is that it writes a document for each game's data each time the function is run. So if I trigger the API on the function twice a day or more it will have multiple documents for each game. When what i want to do is update the document already created. The point of this is to update any changes in the data for the game.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new question in which you're specifying what you want. The question differs from this original question. I would also try to answer the question which you are posting. Also, please see [what I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)